# App_globalResources Folder in MVC 5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resources, asp.net-mvc-5

I was using resource files for language swapping. But it was not working in deployed server. So to the root folder i added App_GlobalResources folder and put the resource files in there. But now i cant make the file as public so its not accessible from model.

I tried to change the property of resource files to GlobalResourceProxyGenerator but still its not accessible :(

is there any naming convention for that app_gloablresources folder?

Please help me out of this...

Answer (score 0):

With the risk of stating the obvious:

When you double click the .resx file you get the gui with the settings.
At the top there is the Access modifier which you can set to Public.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue with two set of same language resource files. The issue was the public access specifier was not taking by Model's display names so i created a second file for Models with the Global access specifier. Now both working fine. Thanks all for the time spend on this :)